# Angular 2 - ng-bootstrap - Scrolling missing from opening second Modal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using modals in my application with NgbModal. I click on a button to open a modal and that is fine. On this modal I have a button which will open another modal which is large and needs to be scrolled. When I open this second modal I am unable to scroll down it and I can see the scrollbar is missing. See the screenshot below.

[Scrollbar missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njRZ7.png)

I am using the following code to open this second modal:

```
        <edit-rule-modal-component [selectedStatementRule]="rule" [includeButtonIcon]="false"
        (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')"></edit-rule-modal-component>
```

As shown in the code the active modal is closed. If I remove this click event so the active modal is not closed then i do not get this issue and the scrollbars appear as expected as shown below.

[Scrollbar present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAP9J.png)

Is there a fix or workaround to this please?